# Newtonsoft.Json dynamic exception in Xamarin.Forms - only in IOS/Device/Release

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, json.net

My Xamarin.Forms app throws exception:

> Microsoft.CSharp.Runtime-Binder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Jobject"

This only happens in the iOS release version installed on device (either by Xamarin on my device, or from Apple Store by customers). It works fine on Android (same code!), also tested on iOS Simulator, both Debug and Release - works fine.

The code is here (2nd line throws):

```cs
dynamic json = JObject.Parse(message);
long time = (long)(json["timestamp"]);
```

Any idea? Maybe some release mode optimizer removes something what should not be removed?

Thanks

Comment: you cannot use `dynamic` on iOS.  Apple prohibits runtime code generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Xamarin.iOS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations#no-dynamic-code-generation)

> Since the iOS kernel prevents an application from generating code dynamically, Xamarin.iOS does not support any form of dynamic code generation.

According to [this blog entry](https://www.wintellect.com/cant-use-dynamic-c-keyword-xamarin-ios/) this includes the use of the `dynamic` type. For reasons (that are not necessarily important for the scope of this answer).

The reason it runs on the simulator is that the simulator does not actually run iOS (not an emulator), but rather is a GUI layer put on top of macOS on which dynamic code generation is allowed.

However, [`JObject` defines an indexer](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm) to access the values contained in the JSON string, hence you do not need `dynamic` at all, but can replace it with `var` in the given context

```cs
var json = JObject.Parse(message);
long time = (long)(json["timestamp"]);
```

This way your `json` variable is a statically typed `JObject`, which is resolved at compile time, hence there is no dynamic code generation that fails on iOS.

Comment: Thanks, going to give a try. Btw, then why it runs fine on iOS (device, not emulator)  in **debug** mode?

Comment: Hm, don't know. Did you enable linking for Release mode? Maybe if linking is not enabled, there is no dynamic code generated, because the indexer exists, but is linked away when the linker is enabled.

Comment: That could be the answer!